# Integrated Foursquare to googlemapv2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, foursquare

any idea how to integrated Foursquare to google map v2 android?
so when im using my google map i can share my location by foursquare.

Comment: To get lat/lons of places around you, look at the [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) or [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) endpoints on Foursquare. You can then use the lat/lons to place pins on Google Maps

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the foursquare api.

> https://developer.foursquare.com/overview

for getting details about venues see:

> https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues

for checking in to share your location

> https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add